# Using Parseval's Identity

Tags: calculus, integration, parsevals-identity

Using parsevals Identity we have obtained that

$$t = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{i(-1)^ne^{-int}}{n} $$,

and $c_0=0$

, prove that $\frac{\pi^2}{6}= \sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

I am really struglling this problem.
I have integate both sides to get $t^2/2 \mid^?_? = \sum \frac{(-1)^ne^{-int}}{n^2}\mid^?_?$, however any evauation point does not appear to work.

Comment: Is the function $\;f(t)=t\;$ ? Then by Dirichlet's theorem that Fourier series isn't equal to the function but rtather to the function's average...I'm guessing it is taken in the interval $\;[-\pi, \pi]\;$ ? Besides this, the right side of the first equation is valid only for $\;n\neq0\;$ .

Comment: Wikipedia seems to take a [slightly different approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Another_rigorous_proof_using_Parseval's_identity)

Answer (score 2):

Parseval's identity tells us that

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|^2dt=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2$$

Do this and you get exactly what you need (Basel Problem solved)